# Expo push notification [listener while app closed or killed and collapse key]

Tags: javascript, react-native, push-notification, expo

Why no direct answer if expo notfication work while app killed or closed and collapse the notfications . I dig and tried much without success .. Can't someone tell me is it possible to interact with app while its closed like reply on messages of whatsapp , can we collapse the notifications ?

I was hope expo is made to make life easy but I spend long time digging as same as with bare react native before